# Passing QByteArray image from c++ to QML

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades, qbytearray

I need to show a png image in a QML page using a QByteArray passed from c++ routines to QML.How can i do this.? Please help me with this guys..

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have your data in a `QByteArray` named `data`, this should work:

```
QImage image;
image.loadFromData(data);
const QImage swappedImage = image.rgbSwapped();
const bb::ImageData imageData = bb::ImageData::fromPixels(swappedImage.bits(), bb::PixelFormat::RGBA_Premultiplied, swappedImage.width(), swappedImage.height(), swappedImage.bytesPerLine());

_image = bb::cascades::Image(imageData);
```

You can now display `_image` in an `ImageView` in your QML code. To achieve this, you'll have to convert it in a `QVariant`: `QVariant::fromValue(_image);`. Once done, you can display it in any `ImageView`. I assume you have an object named `feed` which has an `image` property (`QVariant`):

```
ImageView {
    image: feed.image
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

How can i pass this _image to ImageView in QML.?I tried many method,but it all fails...!!

Comment: I updated my answer to explain this. Basically, you have to convert your image in a ``QVariant``, then everything will just work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
One more help please.How can i set an image property (QVaiant) to the object named feed.

Comment: My "feed" object is an object exported from C++. Its class declares different properties with the ``Q_PROPERTY`` macro: https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/properties.html

Comment: Will u please give me a sample code for the implementation of Q_PROPERTY for this scenario.Because the documentation is bit confusing.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: My full ``Feed`` class is available here: https://github.com/Kernald/tt-rss-bb10/blob/master/src/data/feed.hpp - note that ``image`` is now ``icon``.

Comment: It did the magic.Thank you so much for helping me...:)